# Using jquery-ui dialog as a confirm dialog with an ASP:LinkButton (how to invoke the postbck)

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, webforms

I'd like to use jQuery UI's dialog to implement a confirm dialog which is shown when the user clicks a delete-link (implemented using an `asp:LinkButton`).
I'm using code as shown below (copied from the jquery ui documentation):

```
<!-- the delete link -->
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete"
  OnClick="btnDelete_Click" CssClass="btnDelete"></asp:LinkButton>

<!-- the confirm-dialog -->
<div id="dialog-confirm-delete" title="Delete?" style="display:none;">
  <p>Are you sure you want to permanently deleted the selected items?</p>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    // setup the dialog
    $('#dialog-confirm-delete').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
          "Delete all items": function () {
                 $(this).dialog("close");
                 // ===>>> how to invoke the default action here
              },
          Cancel: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    });

    // display the dialog
    $('.btnDelete').click(function () {
        $('#dialog-confirm-cancel').dialog('open');
        // return false to prevent the default action (postback)
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

So in the `click` event handler, I have to prevent the default action of the `LinkButton` (the postback) and instead display the dialog.

My question is: how can I then invoke the default action (the postback) of the delete link to perform the postback in case the user clicked the "Delete all items" button in the dialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, here's my approach (it works, but it might not be the best solution):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#dialog-confirm-cancel').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Delete all items": function () {
        // invoke the href (postback) of the linkbutton,
        // that triggered the confirm-dialog
        eval($(this).dialog('option', 'onOk'));
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      Cancel: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
    }
  });

  $('.btnDelete').click(function () {
    $('#dialog-confirm-delete')
      // pass the value of the LinkButton's href to the dialog
      .dialog('option', 'onOk', $(this).attr('href'))
      .dialog('open');
    // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: What does `eval()`ing the href do? Is the href not a URL? Also, did my edited answer not work?

Comment: @Drackir: It's not a path to a file. I want to invoke the PostBack of the LinkButton, which is a javascript function call, e.g. __doPostback(...)

Comment: @Drackir: yes, exactly (that's the way how postbacks work in ASP.NET)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not doing anything more than confirming you can add an attribute to the button.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete"
  OnClientClick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?'))return false;" CssClass="btnDelete"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Or better yet `return confirm("Are you sure?");`. However, M4N said that they are using jQuery Dialogs for this and so they probably want to keep a coherent feel for all message boxes/pop-ups.

Comment: lol i couldnt remember what it was, I havent used webforms in a couple years. I guess you can do that on action links as well, but yea its understandable if you're keeping a unified look.  It just seems like a lot of work for a confirm dailog.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a simple confirm dialog. The dialog also contains other elements (textboxes, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Project Awesome on Codeplex](http://awesome.codeplex.com/) it has a generic implementation of a Confirm Dialog that you can inspect for your scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `$("#yourformid").submit();` at this spot `// ===>>> how to invoke the default action here`.
According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/): "... the default submit action on the form will be fired, so the form will be submitted."

**Edit**
You can try to do something like this:

```
$('.btnDelete').click(function (event, confirmed) {
    if (confirmed) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $('#dialog-confirm-cancel').dialog('open');
        // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
        return false;
    }
});
```

And then in your delete all items function:

```
"Delete all items": function () {
    $(this).dialog("close");
    $('.btnDelete').trigger("click", [true]);
},
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. I have to invoke the LinkButton's PostBack.

Comment: @M4N - Have you tried calling the `.click()` function on the button ID? Ex: `$("#buttonid").click();` You may need to get the button's ClientID at runtime for this to be sure Asp.Net doesn't screw up the name. I don't have Asp.Net here but it should be something like this: `$("#<%= btnDelete.ClientID %>").click();`

Comment: Wouldn't that trigger the click event handler once again?

Comment: @M4N - Good point. What if you stored a global variable as to whether or not it had been confirmed and if it has, ignore the dialog open and return true? I also have another idea that doesn't require a global variable which I will edit into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So you prevented the default action of the link(following the link), right? So adding `location.replace('path/to/file');` after `$(this).dialog('close');` would solve your problem.

Not sure I understood your question right though.

Comment: I don't have a path to a file. I want to invoke the PostBack of the LinkButton (which is a javascript function call: __doPostback(...))

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dialog-confirm-delete').dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   modal: true,
   buttons: {
       Cancel: function() {
           $(this).dialog("close");
       },
       "Delete all items": function() {
           $(this).dialog("close");
           // ===>>> how to invoke the default action here
       }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a LinkButton you can do this:

__doPostBack("<%= lnkMyButton.UniqueID %>", "");